# Does Kafka_configs.sh has the ability to alter partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka

While working on a alter Kafka topic job. I found `Kafka-topic.sh` for alter will be deprecated in future release so I am migrating to `Kafka_configs.sh`.

I couldn't find the option to alter the partition with `Kafka_configs.sh`. Is it supported by Kafka_configs.

ex :
`Kafka_topics.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER_URL --alter --topic $TOPIC_NAME --partitions 40`

What is the equivalent of this with `Kafka_configs.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I think not. The call is below:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server <<broker_host:port>> --alter --topic <<topic name>> --partitions <<number of partitions>>
```

See: [Modifying topics](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic)

Comment: The `--zookeeper` flag is deprecated and will be removed soon. It's better to point to the current recommended command:
`> bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server broker_host:port --alter --topic my_topic_name --partitions 40`
See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic